# Generate Class-Path attribute for JAR manifest

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am new to Gradle and Groovy. What is the most concise way to generate Class-Path attribute for JAR manifest using Gradle? Here is what I have come to so far:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13
}

version = '1.0.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
// My dependencies
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'package01.Main'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect{'lib/' + it.name}.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': mainClassName
        )
    }
}
```

The most important line here is:

```
'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect{'lib/' + it.name}.join(' ')
```

Comment: Sample looks concise enough to me. Are you facing any issue? Also, from your question it appears that you are using Groovy. In that case you can apply groovy plugin by adding id: ‘groovy’ in plugin closure.

Comment: @Mamun Everything works fine, I just wanted to know if it's the way to go, or improvements can be made. I'm using Groovy in `build.gradle` and Java for the main application.